# Adding jquery to CSS menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, onhover

I have a css menu that needs a jquery. Sadly, i have a hard time figuring it out.
Below is the mock up of it. When you hover over the topmost menu, a dropdown will appear.
Using jquery, the first child should open its child then switch class if you hover on other sublink and open its child.

[image: Mock up]

```
Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ciancastillo/wtruM/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a jQuery function to an HTML element, use load()

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#idOfItem').load(function() {
          $("td").hover( 
               function () {
                    $(this).addClass("hover");
               }, 
               function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("hover");
          });
      });
 </script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

If you want to bind to an entire class (like say .dropdownItem) use a different selector:

```
 $('.dropdownItem').load(function() {
          //Your code here
      });
```

More jQuery selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Add or remove CSS classes: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: Thanks but to be more specific, I only need the jquery code. The menu is already working but the auto select first-child of toplevel menu and change class if they hover on another sublink 1.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Please look at the mock up.
When you hover the "LINK1", the dropdown will appear with the first-child already highlighted.

(bottom mock up) - When you hover to another "sublink" the first-childs' highlight will transfer to the hovers'

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you please view my fiddle? Thank you